Can't change library code, because my project is in android
Helo,
I've got a library named
implementation 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'

My problem is, that in this library there is a class named ReccurencePickerDialogFragment.java, where you can set the recurrence to hourly. I want to disable that.
I tried to copy ReccurencePickerDialogFragment.java into my project. Then I tried to delete the hourly setting in the array.
But my problem is an other:
My project is in androidx, but com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library is not in androidx. It's the old AppCompat.
When I try to change the class to androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment the problem is that the whole module won't work.
So what can I do?

You could update the whole module to modern standards, since that project is rather old. Or, replace it with another third-party library. Or, implement your own recurrence picker.

create a class with the same name and package in your project, extend that class and override the method?

Here is a fork of the repo where evidently it was updated to androidx.  (Though not sure how to verify this.)  This was determined in the issue section of the original repo.

git clone https://github.com/wwwhackcom/android-betterpickers.git
